# Slow server performance - mod_fcgid causing (104), (09) and (32) errors: mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request_ipc function

Tags: debian, apache-httpd, mysql, php

I'm having trouble with tracking the source of slow web server performance for wordpress site and non-cached pages.

**Server OS**: Debian 8 "Jesssie)" - Linux version 4.9.58-xxxx-std-ipv6-64 (kernel@kernel.ovh.net) (gcc version 6.3.0 20170516 (Debian 6.3.0-18) ) #1 SMP Mon Oct 23 11:35:59 CEST 2017 (**Ispconfig**)

**Web server**: Server version: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)

**PHP** (default): PHP 7.0.26

**PHP** (selected): PHP Version 7.1.8

**Procesor**:  Intel  2x Xeon E5-2630v3 - 16/32t - 2.4GHz /3.2GHz

**RAM**:  128GB DDR4 ECC 1866 MHz

**Disks**: SoftRaid 2x450GB SSD NVMe

**apache2.conf**:

```
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 300
KeepAliveTimeout 5
```

**Server-status** (for last 40 minutes):

```
Server Version: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) mod_fastcgi/mod_fastcgi-SNAP-0910052141 mod_fcgid/2.3.9 mod_python/3.3.1 Python/2.7.9 OpenSSL/1.0.1t
Server MPM: worker
Server Built: Sep 20 2017 04:37:43

Current Time: Monday, 22-Jan-2018 05:24:45 EST
Restart Time: Monday, 22-Jan-2018 04:43:55 EST
Parent Server Config. Generation: 1
Parent Server MPM Generation: 0
Server uptime: 40 minutes 50 seconds
Server load: 0.06 0.09 0.33
Total accesses: 8359 - Total Traffic: 147.2 MB
CPU Usage: u20.73 s2.61 cu0 cs0 - .953% CPU load
3.41 requests/sec - 61.5 kB/second - 18.0 kB/request
13 requests currently being processed, 237 idle workers
```

**apache2ctl -M**:

```
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 watchdog_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 unixd_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 actions_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 auth_digest_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 dav_module (shared)
 dav_fs_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 expires_module (shared)
 fastcgi_module (shared)
 fcgid_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 include_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 mpm_worker_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 proxy_module (shared)
 proxy_fcgi_module (shared)
 python_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 socache_shmcb_module (shared)
 ssl_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
 suexec_module (shared)
```

**Server MPM: worker**:

```
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
        StartServers             10
        MinSpareThreads          25
        MaxSpareThreads          400
        ThreadLimit              64
        ThreadsPerChild          25
        MaxRequestWorkers        500
        MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
```

**my.cnf** (MySQL):

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 61440M
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_log_file_size = 1024M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=60
key_buffer              = 2048M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit       = 1M
query_cache_size        = 0
query_cache_type        = 0
#query_cache_size        = 8192M
```

**domain.com.vhost-le-ssl.conf**
(...)

```
<Directory /var/www/domain.com/web>
                                # Clear PHP settings of this website
                                <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml)$">
                                                SetHandler None
                                </FilesMatch>
                                Options +FollowSymLinks
                                AllowOverride All
                                                                Require all granted
                                                </Directory>
                <Directory /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web>
                                # Clear PHP settings of this website
                                <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml)$">
                                                SetHandler None
                                </FilesMatch>
                                Options +FollowSymLinks
                                AllowOverride All
                                                                Require all granted
                                                </Directory>




                # suexec enabled
                <IfModule mod_suexec.c>
                        SuexecUserGroup web1 client1
                </IfModule>
                # php as fast-cgi enabled
        # For config options see: http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html
                <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
                                FcgidIdleTimeout 300
                                FcgidProcessLifeTime 3600
                                FcgidInitialEnv PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS 10000
                                #FcgidMaxProcesses 1000
                                FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess 10000
                                FcgidMinProcessesPerClass 0
                                FcgidMaxProcessesPerClass 10
                                FcgidConnectTimeout 20
                                FcgidIOTimeout 600
                                FcgidBusyTimeout 3600
                                FcgidOutputBufferSize   0
                                # FcgidBusyScanInterval 120
                                FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824
                </IfModule>
                <Directory /var/www/domain.com/web>
                                <FilesMatch "\.php[345]?$">
                                        SetHandler fcgid-script
                                </FilesMatch>
                                FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web1/.php-fcgi-starter .php
                                FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web1/.php-fcgi-starter .php3
                                FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web1/.php-fcgi-starter .php4
                                FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web1/.php-fcgi-starter .php5
                                Options +ExecCGI
                                AllowOverride All
                                                                Require all granted
                                                </Directory>
                <Directory /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web>
                                <FilesMatch "\.php[345]?$">
                                        SetHandler fcgid-script
                                </FilesMatch>
                                FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web1/.php-fcgi-starter .php
                                FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web1/.php-fcgi-starter .php3
                                FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web1/.php-fcgi-starter .php4
                                FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web1/.php-fcgi-starter .php5
Options +ExecCGI
                                AllowOverride All
                                                                Require all granted
                                                </Directory>



                # add support for apache mpm_itk
                <IfModule mpm_itk_module>
                        AssignUserId web1 client1
                </IfModule>

                <IfModule mod_dav_fs.c>
                # Do not execute PHP files in webdav directory
                        <Directory /var/www/clients/client1/web1/webdav>
                                <ifModule mod_security2.c>
                                        SecRuleRemoveById 960015
                                        SecRuleRemoveById 960032
                                </ifModule>
                                <FilesMatch "\.ph(p3?|tml)$">
                                        SetHandler None
                                </FilesMatch>
                        </Directory>
                        DavLockDB /var/www/clients/client1/web1/tmp/DavLock
                        # DO NOT REMOVE THE COMMENTS!
                        # IF YOU REMOVE THEM, WEBDAV WILL NOT WORK ANYMORE!
      # WEBDAV BEGIN
                        # WEBDAV END
                </IfModule>
(...)
```

**Problem**:

I host a single **wordpress website** on this machine. (32) error appeared from time to time even when the website was in development and the only user was me. Currently I have about 5k unique visitors per day (https://domain.com) and my **error.log** displays multiple (104), (9) and (32) erros, including:

```
    (...)
        (104)Connection reset by peer: [client: XXX.XX.XX.XX:XXXX] mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server
        (104)Connection reset by peer: [client: XXX.XX.XX.XX:XXXX] mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request_ipc function
        (9)Bad file descriptor: [client: XXX.XX.XX.XX:XXXX] mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request_ipc function
        (32)Broken pipe: [client: XXX.XX.XX.XX:XXXX] mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request_ipc function
(104)Connection reset by peer: [client: XXX.XX.XX.XX:XXXX] mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server, referer: https://domain.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=XXXXXXX&action=edit
    (...)
```

The most common error is:

```
(32)Broken pipe: [client: XXX.XX.XX.XX:XXXX] mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request_ipc function
```

I would say that this errors occurs for 5%-10% of all visits and the number is currently low only due to the fact that majority of my pages are cached. This starts to worry me as my website is getting more hits day by day and more visitors are registering and using "search" option or just clicks on "tag" links which are not cached due to its dynamic content.

From what I noticed, these errors occurs mostly when PHP is running. For test I have opened around 20 post in tabs and clicked "edit" button. This caused (104), (9) and (32) errors. (32) appears also when visitor is doing search. In total I have about 500k post in my wordpress.

**What I did to try to fix it** (NO SUCCESS):
**1**. I switched from **PHP-FPM** to **Fast-CGI** and opened 20 post in tabs and clicked "edit" button. Erros still show up in error.log and and post are not loading with browser displaying "**Waiting for available socket**" (**cached pages works super-fast**).

**ps aux | grep "php"**

```
root      7554  0.0  0.0 210764 24084 ?        Ss    2017   0:47 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
root     21443  0.0  0.0 280056  8700 ?        Ss   05:49   0:00 php-fpm: master process (/opt/php-7.1/etc/php-fpm.conf)
www-data 21444  0.0  0.0 280056  6904 ?        S    05:49   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
www-data 21445  0.0  0.0 280056  6904 ?        S    05:49   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
web1     21801  1.4  0.0 367796 83900 ?        S    05:49   0:05 /opt/php-7.1/bin/php-cgi -d open_basedir=/var/www/clients/client1/web1/web:/var/www/clients/client1/web1/private:/var/www/clients/client1/web1/tmp:/var/www/domain.com/web:/srv/www/domain.com/web:/usr/share/php5:/usr/share/php:/tmp:/usr/share/phpmyadmin:/etc/phpmyadmin:/var/lib/phpmyadmin:/dev/random:/dev/urandom -d upload_tmp_dir=/var/www/clients/client1/web1/tmp -d session.save_path=/var/www/clients/client1/web1/tmp -d sendmail_path=/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f webmaster@domain.com
web1     21802  0.9  0.0 367716 81768 ?        S    05:49   0:03 /opt/php-7.1/bin/php-cgi -d open_basedir=/var/www/clients/client1/web1/web:/var/www/clients/client1/web1/private:/var/www/clients/client1/web1/tmp:/var/www/domain.com/web:/srv/www/domain.com/web:/usr/share/php5:/usr/share/php:/tmp:/usr/share/phpmyadmin:/etc/phpmyadmin:/var/lib/phpmyadmin:/dev/random:/dev/urandom -d upload_tmp_dir=/var/www/clients/client1/web1/tmp -d session.save_path=/var/www/clients/client1/web1/tmp -d sendmail_path=/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f webmaster@domain.com
web1     21803  0.7  0.0 291716 80684 ?        S    05:49   0:02 /opt/php-7.1/bin/php-cgi -d open_basedir=/var/www/clients/client1/web1/web:/var/www/clients/client1/web1/private:/var/www/clients/client1/web1/tmp:/var/www/domain.com/web:/srv/www/domain.com/web:/usr/share/php5:/usr/share/php:/tmp:/usr/share/phpmyadmin:/etc/phpmyadmin:/var/lib/phpmyadmin:/dev/random:/dev/urandom -d upload_tmp_dir=/var/www/clients/client1/web1/tmp -d session.save_path=/var/www/clients/client1/web1/tmp -d sendmail_path=/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f webmaster@domain.com
web1     21804  0.6  0.0 367656 81500 ?        S    05:49   0:02 /opt/php-7.1/bin/php-cgi -d open_basedir=/var/www/clients/client1/web1/web:/var/www/clients/client1/web1/private:/var/www/clients/client1/web1/tmp:/var/www/domain.com/web:/srv/www/domain.com/web:/usr/share/php5:/usr/share/php:/tmp:/usr/share/phpmyadmin:/etc/phpmyadmin:/var/lib/phpmyadmin:/dev/random:/dev/urandom -d upload_tmp_dir=/var/www/clients/client1/web1/tmp -d session.save_path=/var/www/clients/client1/web1/tmp -d sendmail_path=/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f webmaster@domain.com
web1     21805  0.4  0.0 291716 80304 ?        S    05:49   0:01 /opt/php-7.1/bin/php-cgi -d open_basedir=/var/www/clients/client1/web1/web:/var/www/clients/client1/web1/private:/var/www/clients/client1/web1/tmp:/var/www/domain.com/web:/srv/www/domain.com/web:/usr/share/php5:/usr/share/php:/tmp:/usr/share/phpmyadmin:/etc/phpmyadmin:/var/lib/phpmyadmin:/dev/random:/dev/urandom -d upload_tmp_dir=/var/www/clients/client1/web1/tmp -d session.save_path=/var/www/clients/client1/web1/tmp -d sendmail_path=/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f webmaster@domain.com
web1     21817  0.3  0.0 366944 80224 ?        S    05:49   0:01 /opt/php-7.1/bin/php-cgi -d open_basedir=/var/www/clients/client1/web1/web:/var/www/clients/client1/web1/private:/var/www/clients/client1/web1/tmp:/var/www/domain.com/web:/srv/www/domain.com/web:/usr/share/php5:/usr/share/php:/tmp:/usr/share/phpmyadmin:/etc/phpmyadmin:/var/lib/phpmyadmin:/dev/random:/dev/urandom -d upload_tmp_dir=/var/www/clients/client1/web1/tmp -d session.save_path=/var/www/clients/client1/web1/tmp -d sendmail_path=/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f webmaster@domain.com
web1     21818  0.7  0.0 361524 76512 ?        S    05:49   0:02 /opt/php-7.1/bin/php-cgi -d open_basedir=/var/www/clients/client1/web1/web:/var/www/clients/client1/web1/private:/var/www/clients/client1/web1/tmp:/var/www/domain.com/web:/srv/www/domain.com/web:/usr/share/php5:/usr/share/php:/tmp:/usr/share/phpmyadmin:/etc/phpmyadmin:/var/lib/phpmyadmin:/dev/random:/dev/urandom -d upload_tmp_dir=/var/www/clients/client1/web1/tmp -d session.save_path=/var/www/clients/client1/web1/tmp -d sendmail_path=/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f webmaster@domain.com
web1     21998  0.8  0.0 369600 85560 ?        S    05:50   0:02 /opt/php-7.1/bin/php-cgi -d open_basedir=/var/www/clients/client1/web1/web:/var/www/clients/client1/web1/private:/var/www/clients/client1/web1/tmp:/var/www/domain.com/web:/srv/www/domain.com/web:/usr/share/php5:/usr/share/php:/tmp:/usr/share/phpmyadmin:/etc/phpmyadmin:/var/lib/phpmyadmin:/dev/random:/dev/urandom -d upload_tmp_dir=/var/www/clients/client1/web1/tmp -d session.save_path=/var/www/clients/client1/web1/tmp -d sendmail_path=/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f webmaster@domain.com
web1     22192  3.9  0.0 289668 79848 ?        S    05:53   0:06 /opt/php-7.1/bin/php-cgi -d open_basedir=/var/www/clients/client1/web1/web:/var/www/clients/client1/web1/private:/var/www/clients/client1/web1/tmp:/var/www/domain.com/web:/srv/www/domain.com/web:/usr/share/php5:/usr/share/php:/tmp:/usr/share/phpmyadmin:/etc/phpmyadmin:/var/lib/phpmyadmin:/dev/random:/dev/urandom -d upload_tmp_dir=/var/www/clients/client1/web1/tmp -d session.save_path=/var/www/clients/client1/web1/tmp -d sendmail_path=/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f webmaster@domain.com
web1     22193  0.8  0.0 285392 75288 ?        S    05:53   0:01 /opt/php-7.1/bin/php-cgi -d open_basedir=/var/www/clients/client1/web1/web:/var/www/clients/client1/web1/private:/var/www/clients/client1/web1/tmp:/var/www/domain.com/web:/srv/www/domain.com/web:/usr/share/php5:/usr/share/php:/tmp:/usr/share/phpmyadmin:/etc/phpmyadmin:/var/lib/phpmyadmin:/dev/random:/dev/urandom -d upload_tmp_dir=/var/www/clients/client1/web1/tmp -d session.save_path=/var/www/clients/client1/web1/tmp -d sendmail_path=/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f webmaster@domain.com
ispconf+ 22268  0.0  0.0 285232 22940 ?        Ss   05:54   0:00 /usr/bin/php-cgi -d disable_classes= -d disable_functions= -d magic_quotes_gpc=off -d open_basedir= -d session.save_path=/usr/local/ispconfig/interface/temp
ispconf+ 22270  0.1  0.0 285528 16064 ?        S    05:54   0:00 /usr/bin/php-cgi -d disable_classes= -d disable_functions= -d magic_quotes_gpc=off -d open_basedir= -d session.save_path=/usr/local/ispconfig/interface/temp
root     22433  0.0  0.0  13216  2172 pts/0    S+   05:55   0:00 grep php
root     24127  0.0  0.0 306300  8952 ?        Ss    2017   0:37 php-fpm: master process (/usr/local/php-7.1.8/etc/php-fpm.conf)
www-data 24128  0.0  0.0 306640  9228 ?        S     2017   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
www-data 24129  0.0  0.0 306300  6980 ?        S     2017   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
www-data 29862  0.0  0.0 213180 19708 ?        S    Jan19   0:04 php-fpm: pool www
www-data 29891  0.0  0.0 213176 21532 ?        S    Jan19   0:04 php-fpm: pool www
www-data 29948  0.0  0.0 211136 17540 ?        S    Jan19   0:03 php-fpm: pool www
```

**TOP**:

```
top - 06:02:08 up 27 days, 17:45,  1 user,  load average: 2.45, 3.20, 2.26
Tasks: 487 total,   1 running, 486 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 12.5 us,  3.6 sy,  0.0 ni, 83.4 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.5 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:  13198007+total, 12718466+used,  4795408 free,  2421808 buffers
KiB Swap:  1046520 total,        0 used,  1046520 free. 10000835+cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
27655 mysql     20   0 68.220g 0.012t  11640 S 519.8 10.1   3798:47 mysqld
21602 www-data  20   0 2058172  17132   7092 S   0.3  0.0   0:00.77 apache2
(...)
```

**Edit**:

These MySQL queries generates 128.9% CPU usage by mysqld:

```
    mysql> show full processlist;
+--------+---------------+-----------+---------------+---------+------+----------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Id     | User          | Host      | db            | Command | Time | State                | Info                                                                                                                                                                                 |
+--------+---------------+-----------+---------------+---------+------+----------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 284863 | root          | localhost | c1DATABASE | Query   |    0 | NULL                 | show full processlist                                                                                                                                                                |
| 287063 | c1DATABASE | localhost | c1DATABASE | Sleep   |    0 |                      | NULL                                                                                                                                                                                 |
| 287064 | c1DATABASE | localhost | c1DATABASE | Query   |    0 | Sorting result       | SELECT  t.*, tt.* FROM wp_terms AS t  INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('post_tag') AND tt.count > 0 ORDER BY tt.count DESC LIMIT 45 |
| 287065 | c1DATABASE | localhost | c1DATABASE | Query   |    1 | Copying to tmp table | SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0, 10                |
| 287066 | c1DATABASE | localhost | c1DATABASE | Sleep   |    0 |                      | NULL                                                                                                                                                                                 |
+--------+---------------+-----------+---------------+---------+------+----------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**2**. I have updated and tweaked following options:

```
FcgidBusyTimeout 3600
FcgidProcessLifeTime 3600
FcgidOutputBufferSize   0
```

**Sources**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33811543/php-and-mod-fcgid-ap-pass-brigade-failed-in-handle-request-ipc-function

[Apache mod_fcgid documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html#examples) lists out another possibility which the "**mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request_ipc function**" error may occur, which is due to limit of **PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS** and/or **FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess**. PHP FastCGI processes exit after handling 500 requests, and they may exit after this module has already connected to the application and sent the next request, resulting in "mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request_ipc function" error.

As per Apache mod_fcgid documentation and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12477627/mod-fcgid-ap-pass-brigade-failed-in-handle-request-function), I have also updated following options:

```
FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess 10000
FcgidInitialEnv PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS 10000
```

**Sources**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12477627/mod-fcgid-ap-pass-brigade-failed-in-handle-request-function

Unfortunately, both **1**) and **2**) did not solved my problem :-/ 
Any advice how to squiz max out of this machine (Intel 2x Xeon E5-2630v3 - 16/32t - 2.4GHz /3.2GHz + 128GB DDR4 ECC 1866 MHz RAM) and fix the problem with **mod_fcgid** erros?
Cheers!

Comment: Could it be that the connection to the client has been cut?  Is there anything between your browser and the Apache server?   Firewall, Reverse Cache, ...

Comment: I just saw that mysqld is taking 520% of cpu.   You might have to take a look at your database design.

Comment: I have edited my question and added the output of **SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST** query. Above generates +/-500% of CPU when I'm opening 20 post in new tabs and click "edit" button. Thanks @gerard-h-pille :)

Comment: We can't see the full query.  `select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST where db = 'c1'` might help.

Comment: Question update, thank you @gerard-h-pille :)

Comment: Can you add a description of the wp_postmeta table (+ how many rows) and any indexes involving the meta_key column.

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_postmeta; COUNT(*)  
12690066 Each post features information called the meta data and it is stored in the wp_postmeta. Some plugins may add their own information to this table: https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_postmeta  @gerard-h-pille

Comment: Can you please show the description of your table and your indexes?

Comment: @gerard-h-pille: Updated :)

Answer (score 2):

The index on meta_key is wrong, it contains only 191 of the 255 possible characters, so mysql will not use it.  That is the cause of your slow query.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37675274/wordpress-query-slow-with-many-posts-and-custom-fields

This person (Killer Loop) changed meta_key in wp_postmeta to 191 characters, and got results 2/10th seconds.

Comment: @gerard-h-pille Altrhought your solution has decreased CPU load caused by MySQL (**Thank you very much for this!**), the main problem still persists:  `(32)Broken pipe: [client XXX.XX.XX.XX:XXXXX] mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request_ipc function`

Comment: Can you update the "show full processlist"?

Comment: @gerard-h-pille: Done :)

Comment: I don't see the "show full processlist".  Only the "information_schema.processlist" which has become difficult to read.  I'll be AFK for an hour or so.

Comment: @gerard-h-pille: Updated, thank you very much for your help and assistance :)

Comment: "These MySQL queries generates 226.7% CPU usage by mysqld:".  Are you very sure about that?  I see two queries that have been busy for 0 seconds, the rest of the connections are sleeping.  Please update the TOP statistics to prove you are right.

Comment: @gerard-h-pille: Done :) Ps. I'm thinking about separating bits about MySQL from this post as it looks like that the database issue is something not related to the main problem. Also, this will clean the discussion and makes things easier as I don't want to waste your time :)

Comment: I don't get it.  You had your database consuming 520% CPU, and Apache 0.3%, but the database would not be related to the "main" problem?   What is the main problem?   And TOP still shows 520% CPU.

Comment: I think that the high CPU usage by mysqld is not causing `(32)Broken pipe: [client XXX.XX.XX.XX:XXXXX] mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request_ipc function` error. Obviously there is something wrong with either mysqld or wordpress database, but current average CPU load at 100% does not mean that all 32 cores are in use by mysqld. I will try to re-install PHP packages, including PHP-FPM & FastCGI as I belive that this is the issue with mod_fcgid errors. When fix this I will repost question regarding only wordpress high CPU consumption. Thanks for your help Geard, much appreciated :)

Comment: I think you're wasting your time.  If you change your mind, just add a comment here and we can continue the exercise.  Good luck!